# Задать CSS для всех заглавных букв в label по значению текста или задать значение текста lebel как атрибут

Tags: css, регулярные-выражения, label, stylus

Задача - задать отдельный стиль для всех заглавных букв в тексте `label`. Например, в

```
<label for="dd">Дата РОО</label>

label[value*="/A-Z/"] { color: #17f; }
```

Или как-то задать значение для `label` через атрибут, что бы было

```
<label for="dd" value="Дата РОО"></label>
```

вместо

```
label for="dd">Дата РОО</label>
```

и, затем, сделать CSS для заглавных букв

Использовать должен только CSS или Stylus, без скриптов.

Answer (score 3):

Короткий ответ: на чистом css это сделать невозможно. Нужно использовать javascript.

Длинный ответ:

Символы в тексте не являются элементами DOM. В css существуют псевдоэлементы, которые используются для оформления чего-либо, не являющегося самостоятельным элементом. Примеры: ::before, ::after, ::first-letter. Например, с помощью ::first-letter можно стилизовать первый символ элемента, с помощью ::first-line - первую строку, и т. д. Полный список [здесь](https://webref.ru/css/type/pseudoelement)

Теоретически, если бы существовал псевдоэлемент ::caps-letter, можно было бы задать стиль для заглавных букв в тексте. Но такого элемента нет. Поэтому с помощью css это сделать невозможно.

Stylus - это просто синтаксический сахар для генерации css. Поэтому то, что нельзя сделать на css, нельзя сделать и на Stylus.

Javascript же позволяет создавать и заменять элементы DOM. С его помощью можно заменить содержимое label, выведя каждую заглавную букву в span, которому назначен желаемый стиль.

Comment: Спасибо! Я надеялся, можно для `label` сделать то же самое, что с `input`: `input[value*="T"] { color: #F90; }` и использовать regexp для задания шаблона значения...

Comment: Этот селектор выбирает элементы input, у которых в value содержится "T". Он не выбирает букву, он выбирает весь input целиком.

Comment: да, верно. Я и писал, что вместо "Т" хорошо бы иметь возможность использовать regexp и как-то совместить или иметь подобие `:first-letter`

Comment: Такого в css, к сожалению, тоже нет. Я имею в виду селекторы с использованием полноценных regex. Но на javascript, опять же, это достижимо. Например, можно расширить jquery: https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/165197/